# Is there a way to upload a picture to an html form and then immediate save the same image to the phone/tablet that took it?

Tags: javascript, html, file, save, photo

I have a form where a user can upload an image. Ideally, this image would also save to their machine right after they take the photo.

Right now I am using a simple input type=file to get the user to take a picture.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but out from the top of my dome maybe one of these could drive you in the right direction:

- [Save image to hard drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033854/save-image-to-hard-drive)
- https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web_development/9781849699310/1/ch01lvl1sec21/storing-images-within-local-storage-become-an-expert

I suppose you will always have that protection from the client side where they actually have to accept the save of the file