# Export Highcharts to jsPDF - canvg error

Tags: javascript, canvas, highcharts, jspdf, canvg

I'm looking for a solution about highcharts export to PDF with jsPDF.
I used this solution to export my graph as image to my pdf -> [Export Highcharts to PDF (using javascript and local server - no internet connection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630811/export-highcharts-to-pdf-using-javascript-and-local-server-no-internet-connec?answertab=active#tab-top)

It's working fine, but for some graph i could not generate the image because of this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function -- canvg.js:2000
svg.Element.text.getAnchorDelta -- canvg.js:2010
svg.Element.text.renderChild -- canvg.js:1989
svg.Element.text.renderChildren -- canvg.js:679
svg.Element.ElementBase.render -- canvg.js:698
svg.Element.ElementBase.renderChildren -- canvg.js:679
svg.Element.ElementBase.render -- canvg.js:698
svg.Element.ElementBase.renderChildren -- canvg.js:679
svg.Element.ElementBase.render -- canvg.js:2723
svg.loadXmlDoc.draw -- canvg.js:2733
svg.loadXmlDoc -- canvg.js:2646
svg.loadXml -- canvg.js:62
canvg -- indicateurs.js:3237
$.bind.H.Chart.createCanvas -- indicateurs.js:3171
(anonymous function) -- jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
x.extend.each -- indicateurs.js:3164
_indicateurs.hightcharts.graph_to_pdf -- indicateurs.js:3262
(anonymous function) -- jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5
x.event.dispatch -- jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5
x.event.add.v.handle
```

Following, the canvas method throwing the error (canvg.js) :

```
        this.getAnchorDelta = function (ctx, parent, startI) {
            var textAnchor = this.style('text-anchor').valueOrDefault('start');
            if (textAnchor != 'start') {
                var width = 0;
                for (var i=startI; i<parent.children.length; i++) {
                    var child = parent.children[i];
                    if (i > startI && child.attribute('x').hasValue()) break; // new group
                    width += child.measureTextRecursive(ctx);       // ######## PROBLEM LOCATED ON THIS LINE
                }
                return -1 * (textAnchor == 'end' ? width : width / 2.0);
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Any first ideas about what could be make this error ?

Comment: can you let us know the error you are receiving

Comment: W.onerror : error : Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
 on page: /js/library_bower/canvg/dist/canvg.js
 on line: 2000
 on column: 22
 on object: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: The firefox error seem more readable : TypeError: child.measureTextRecursive is not a function canvg.js:2000:15

Comment: It would be better if you can provide a fiddle

Comment: I could not reproduce it on jsfiddle. I tried to make the more simple exemple. I copied the svg that highcharts provide but it doesn't fail on jsfiddle.... http://fiddle.jshell.net/dct9tfvn/78/

Comment: Cool .. so the problem is solved :p

Comment: ^^ troll-ed! Unfortunately, I can not put all online scripts to reproduce exactly the problem ... That sucks .

Comment: Finally, i used highcharts server side image generation http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/render-charts-serverside

Answer (score 2):

Use this bower package:

```
"canvg-gabelerner": "*"
```

And make sure you include these 3 dependencies:

```
<script src="bower_components/canvg-gabelerner/rgbcolor.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/canvg-gabelerner/StackBlur.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/canvg-gabelerner/canvg.js"></script>
```

The *canvg* bower package is old. It was created because original repo was stored on Google code service (now dead).

I hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

It is one of the common issues in HighCharts. This is due to the wrapped text that is found within the `<title></title>` tag. This usually occurs if your axis labels are too long and they are wrapped to multiple lines. The simple way to resolve this error is to remove all the `title` elements before exporting to PDF. This doesn't affect any part of your chart.

To remove the title element within your chart container, use `JQuery`

```
("#chart_container_id title").remove();
```

Insert this line at the beginning of the exporting module. Now try to export and this will work fine.

Comment: Wow! Great answer!

Comment: Removing title does not work. getSVG() still returns an SVG image with title elements. I have to do svg.replace(/<title>[\w\d\s]*<\/title>/g,''). What am I doing wrong?