# Export Highcharts to PDF with AngularJS Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts-ng

I'm looking to export a customized chart simliar to the post here [Export Highcharts to PDF (using javascript and local server - no internet connection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630811/export-highcharts-to-pdf-using-javascript-and-local-server-no-internet-connec/25632935#25632935) that references http://fiddle.jshell.net/leighking2/dct9tfvn/. This has the exact functionality that I'm looking for, however I have my chart/data in a sepearte file/controller. Does anyone know how I could take the concept from the post I listed above, but incorporate it into my controller?

Didn't want to include my whole index.html file but here are the two charts from it.

```html
 <div id="allCharts" class="col-md-6" >
      <button class="export_all" >export all</button>
            <highchart id="chart1" config="chartConfig" class="span9 myChart" ></highchart>
                <hr>
            <highchart id="chart2" config="chartConfig2" class="span9 myChart" ></highchart>  
 </div>
```

```html
'use strict';

var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["highcharts-ng"]);

myapp.controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {
   
    $scope.chartConfig = {
        options: {
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
            },
            xAxis: {
          categories: ['Year 1', 'Year 2', 'Year 3', 'Year 4', 'Year 5'],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
      },

      plotOptions: {
          line: {
              events: {
                  legendItemClick: function () {
                      return false;
                  }
              }

          }, allowPointSelect: false,
        series: {
          stacking: ''
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{ "name": "Purchase Costs", data: $scope.purchaseChartData }, { "name": "Rental Costs", data: $scope.rentalChartData }],
    title: {
      text: 'Rental and Purchase Costs'
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: true
    },
    loading: false,
    size: {}
    };


    $scope.chartConfig2 = {
        options: {
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            xAxis: {
          categories: ['Year 1', 'Year 2', 'Year 3', 'Year 4', 'Year 5'],
          title: {
              text: null
          }
      },
      plotOptions: {

          column: {
              events: {
                  legendItemClick: function () {
                      return false;
                  }
              }

          }, allowPointSelect: false,
                series: {
                    stacking: ''
                }
            }
        },
        exporting:{
            allowHTML:true
        },
        series: [{ "name": "Annual Savings", data: $scope.savingsChartData }],
        title: {
            useHTML:false,
            text: 'Savings Compounded Annually'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: true
        },
        loading: false,
        size: {}
    };

  $scope.reflow = function () {
    $scope.$broadcast('highchartsng.reflow');
  };


});
```

> Question Update

Thanks Vaelyr! I now have the print button working; however I only have it adding text. I'm just having trouble linking my chart to the imageData. For now I just have the script within my html page until I get this working.

Attaching the charts to the imageData (via a loop) isn't working for me. I have class="myCharts" attached to both of my charts, but no luck. Now I'm just bacially trying to add my charts to the imageData.

```
 <div id="allCharts" class="col-md-6" >
    <button class="exportAll" onClick="printPDF()" id="export_btn">export all</button>
   <highchart id="chart1" config="chartConfig" class="span9 myChart" ></highchart>
      <hr>
 <highchart id="chart2" config="chartConfig2" class="span9 myChart" ></highchart>
```

```
      function printPDF() {
            var doc = new jsPDF();

            // chart height defined here so each chart can be palced
            // in a different position
            var chartHeight = 80;

            // All units are in the set measurement for the document
            // This can be changed to "pt" (points), "mm" (Default), "cm", "in"
            doc.setFontSize(40);
            doc.text(35, 25, "My Exported Charts");

            //loop through each chart
            $('.myChart').each(function (index) {
            var imageData = $(this).highcharts().createCanvas();


            // add image to doc, if you have lots of charts,
            // you will need to check if you have gone bigger 
            // than a page and do doc.addPage() before adding 
            // another image.

            /**
             * addImage(imagedata, type, x, y, width, height)
             */
            doc.addImage(imageData, 'JPEG', 45, (index * chartHeight) + 40, 120, chartHeight);
            //add.addImage();
    });


    //save with name
    doc.save('demo.pdf');
};
```

Comment: How about just get these functions and make them into a directive on your page. Have the export button click handler run the referenced code. Nothing changes really. Idea is still to find all the chart elements, make them into highchart objcets and print on the created canvas. Logic does not change.

Answer (score 0):

I found the functionality that I was looking for here https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/issues/185.

--moe