# Download Highchart Graph on different button click

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, download

I have a Highchart chart in my application and I don't want to use the inbuilt download button of Highcharts to download the chart. What I want is to have some Download button outside the Highchart and upon clicking on that Download button it should download the chart. Can this be done in Highcharts?

Comment: May be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46575211/offline-exporting-a-highcharts-chart-using-an-external-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this documentation I found.

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview

> To unleash the full power of HTML5, it is also possible to fully disregard our built-in button and menu, and build your own buttons or links that call Chart.print() or Chart.exportChart() with parameters.

Comment: If you could solve your problem, please consider marking an answer as correct, so other people with the same question can find a solution quicker.

Comment: just did it now