# Add picture issue when exporting Highcharts to pdf - Highcharts warning: Invalid tagName

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts, pdf-generation

I have an export of Highcharts into a pdf file with added text and images (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54864681/multiple-highcharts-on-a-pdf-page-svg-page-layout)). It used to work until recently but now it's not exporting the added pictures, everything else is fine.

The JavaScript is throwing the following error "Highcharts warning: Invalid tagName image in config". Fiddle reproducing the error [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vicdev12/0daf34g6/18/).

The line that causes the problem is svgImg.appendChild(svgimg).

I'm not sure if I changed something or if there was a library change somewhere. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the js:

```
$(function () {
    
    Highcharts.getSVG = function(charts,texts, options, callback) {
        
  var svgArr = [],
    top = 0,
    width = 0,
    newLine = false,
    txt1;
    addSVG = function(svgres,i) {
        
      // Grab width/height from exported chart
      var svgWidth = +svgres.match(
          /^<svg[^>]*width\s*=\s*\"?(\d+)\"?[^>]*>/
        )[1],
        svgHeight = +svgres.match(
          /^<svg[^>]*height\s*=\s*\"?(\d+)\"?[^>]*>/
        )[1],
        // Offset the position of this chart in the final SVG
        svg;


      
          if (svgWidth > 1100) {
           if(i==5){
                  top = 1000;
                  svg = svgres.replace('<svg', '<g transform="translate(0,' + top + ')"');
              }else{
                  svg = svgres.replace('<svg', '<g transform="translate(' + width + ', 0 )"');
              }
            top = Math.max(top, svgHeight);
    
          } else {
            if (newLine) {
              if(i==4){
                  width = 1000;
              }
              svg = svgres.replace('<svg', '<g transform="translate(' + width + ', ' + top + ')"');
              top += svgHeight;
              width += svgWidth;
              newLine = false;
            } else {
              newLine = true;
              if(i==5){
                  top = 1000;
                  svg = svgres.replace('<svg', '<g transform="translate(0,' + top + ')" ');
              }else{
                  svg = svgres.replace('<svg', '<g transform="translate(0,' + top + ')" ');
              }
              
              top = Math.max(top, svgHeight);
              width += svgWidth;
              //width = Math.max(width, chart.chartWidth);
            }
          }
       
      svg = svg.replace('</svg>', '</g>');
      svgArr.push(svg);
      
       txt = texts[i];
       
        txt1 = '<svg width="350" height="75" viewBox="0 0 350 75"><rect x="10" y="50" 
          width="300" height="40" style="fill: white; stroke:black;stroke-width:2"/><g 
          style="overflow:hidden; font-size:14; font-family: Arial"></text><text x="20" y="65" 
          style="fill: black">Text test text text</text></g><g style="overflow:hidden; font- 
          size:14; font-family: Arial"></text><text x="20" y="82" style="fill: black">Text 
          test text text</text></g></svg>' ;
                
      svgArr.push(txt1);
      
    },
    exportChart = function(i) {
      if (i === charts.length) {
          
          // add SVG image to exported svg
        addSVG(svgImg.outerHTML);
          
          //console.log(top+'-----'+width);
        return callback('<svg height="2000" width="2000" version="1.1" 
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' + svgArr.join('') + '</svg>');
      }
      charts[i].getSVGForLocalExport(options, {}, function() {
        console.log("Failed to get SVG");
      }, function(svg) {
        addSVG(svg,i);
        return exportChart(i + 1); // Export next only when this SVG is received
      });
    };
//     console.log(svgArr);  
  exportChart(0);
};
    
Highcharts.exportCharts = function(charts,texts, options) {
  options = Highcharts.merge(Highcharts.getOptions().exporting, options);

  // Get SVG asynchronously and then download the resulting SVG
  Highcharts.getSVG(charts,texts, options, function(svg) {
    Highcharts.downloadSVGLocal(svg, options, function() {
      console.log("Failed to export on client side");
    });
  });
};

//Set global default options for all charts
Highcharts.setOptions({
  exporting: {
    fallbackToExportServer: false // Ensure the export happens on the client side or not at all
  }
});



var chart1 = new Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        styledMode: true
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Styling axes and columns'
    },

    yAxis: [{
        className: 'highcharts-color-0',
        title: {
            text: 'Primary axis'
        }
    }, {
        className: 'highcharts-color-1',
        opposite: true,
        title: {
            text: 'Secondary axis'
        }
    }],

    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            borderRadius: 5
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [1, 3, 2, 4]
    }, {
        data: [324, 124, 547, 221],
        yAxis: 1
    }]

});

  
var texts = $('.HC');
     
  function toDataURL(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            callback(reader.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.send();
};   
     
var svgImg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
svgImg.setAttribute('xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');
svgImg.setAttribute('height', '200');
svgImg.setAttribute('width', '200');
svgImg.setAttribute('id', 'test');

var svgimg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'image');
svgimg.setAttribute('height', '768');
svgimg.setAttribute('width', '1024');
svgimg.setAttribute('id', 'testimg');

// convert image and add to svg image object
toDataURL('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png', function (dataUrl) {
    svgimg.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', dataUrl);
});

svgimg.setAttribute('x', '0');
svgimg.setAttribute('y', '0');
svgImg.appendChild(svgimg);

     
    $("#export2pdf").click(function() {
        Highcharts.exportCharts([chart1],texts, {
          type: 'application/pdf',
          filename: 'Feedback',
        });
      });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is related to the new Highcharts Security policy. You need to modify the default AST settings:

```
Highcharts.AST.allowedTags.push('image');
Highcharts.AST.allowedAttributes.push('xlink:href');
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8snjc6gy/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/security

Comment: Thank you! This is it. I can't upvote, not enough reputation.