# unable to get the charts in the PDF download

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

There are 3-4 charts in a Html page and i have a **PDF download button** on clicking the download button getting a pdf file in that we are unable to get the charts. we have used kendo drawing to download the Pdf

Below is the code that we have tried:

```
$scope.print = function(){
        kendo.drawing.drawDOM($("#page-Container")).then(function(group) {
            kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group, "PdfDocumnet.pdf");
        });
}
```

Or Any Other Framework can be helpful??

Comment: Check this example with a custom PDF download button. It works without any framework. Maybe it will resolve your issue. http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1o8mp4fL/

Comment: ok, but here the scenario is there are multiple charts. then how can we do this??

Comment: By creating more charts and adding them as a parameter to the exportCharts function. 
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2eym8Ldx/

Comment: Please analyze also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54761784/highcharts-export-multiple-charts-using-jspdf/54768981#54768981

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue kind of like this a while back. From what I remember something was crashing with no error and the promise was never getting called.

For a workaround, a colleague of mine came up with converting the chats to images first.

```
$scope.print = function(){
    kendo.drawing.drawDOM($("#page-Container")).then(function(group) {
       return kendo.drawing.exportImage(group);
    }).done(function (data) {
       // replace chart(s) with png version(s)
       $(".chat").replaceWith("<div class='.chart'><img src='" + date +"' /></div>");

       kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(data, "PdfDocumnet.pdf");
    });
}
```