# Export data table php mysql with chart highchats using jspdf

Tags: javascript, php, html, highcharts, jspdf

**I want to export a table made in html, filled with data from a db using php, and a chart highchars using  jspdf.**

I can export separately, the datatable using jspdf and the chart using his own tool, but I need to export both in a single file like jpg/png or pdf. I tried in highcharts showing the datatable from the actual chart and it works but I can't personalise the datatable with extra info, labels or design. I've tried to put two charts and export both using jspdf, in one the pie chart and in the other only a datatable from a hidden line chart, but the table becomes static and I can't make it responsive or put extra things on it, so it looks bad. 
So it's posible to export the datatable and the chart in a single file using jspdf or something like that?

Comment: If you can add some code snippet or a live demo (via jsfiddle or codesandbox) it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: Hi @Ylion, Please check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54761784/highcharts-export-multiple-charts-using-jspdf You can use the same approach to combine a chart and a table.