# Export to pdf all html page along with highcharts

Tags: asp.net-core, highcharts, export-to-pdf

I am working on a project in asp .net core where I, want to export all my highcharts along with the other html content in to pdf when clicked on export button.

Comment: Hi Pallavi - Could you please add what you have tried and what is not working for you?  A minimal example that shows the problem will help people answer your question.

Comment: Hi Barbara - I have a razor page on which there is some information along with 3 or more highcharts. I want to export all the details to pdf.

Comment: This post [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54761784/highcharts-export-multiple-charts-using-jspdf) how to download multiple charts with `jspdf`. You can try to implement this solution to .NET.

Comment: You can try to use `jsreport .net sdk`, Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39364687/export-html-to-pdf-in-asp-net-core).

Comment: this is solved using export module of Highcharts which will give you image or svg which you can use in creating pdf